# What do I need to do before starting a project?

Tags: design, software

This is quite a silly question, but I really don't know what to do before starting a project.

Take this project for example:

https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd/

This project to me is quite complex. There are a ton of functions: simple as well as Higher-order functions and they interact with each other in a way that is, in my opinion, quite hard to grasp. I don't know how the author can come up with that structure as well as all of those functions.

Does it have anything related to Software Design? How do I chose the project's structure? What do I need to do to decide on the functions, classes that the project needs to have as well as the way that they interact with each other?

Comment: Have you tried a simple project before diving into something so obviously overwhelming? There are plenty of tutorials for beginners out there.

Comment: Higher order functions (functions taking function arguments, e.g. as callbacks) are the norm for JavaScript in the browser: it is the way to handle events.  Further, functions that return functions accomplish closures, which allow for state that lives longer than the one function call, and can be used to share information between functions as well.  So, some of what you mention is programming style in JavaScript for the Browser, rather than software design.  Assuming software design means top-level structure, the software design is in the files & modules, and their organization, etc..

Comment: Semantically, **starting** is the always first thing you do. I assume you mean to ask what you need to do before you start _developing_ a project.

Comment: Yeah. That's actually what I mean. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start off with requirements.

If it's a user application, decide on the Use Cases or User Stories.  These will then drive you towards a top-level architecture.

If it's a library, work out what the callers will want to do with the library, and then decide from that what the top level functions are.  Only once you're happy with those do you work down to the lower level implementation details.

Comment: `If it's a library, work out what the callers will want to do with the library,` is that not really the same as figuring out what a user wants to do with the application? In either case, it's considering the interaction with the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I choose a project's structure? What do I need to do to decide on the functions and classes that the project needs to have as well as the way that they interact with each other?

I think a project's structure should be selected by what the project does. Are you making a library or an application? What is its purpose? How should it be used? What sorts of features would the user want it to have?

In the case of an application, the most common structure is the Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture. There are entire frameworks (like Rails) that are dedicated to this architecture, and they work because like things stick with like things. Code that describes a model sits together in a folder or package called `model`, while controllers sit in `controller`, and views sit in `view`.

Let's take a toy example: suppose you're building a mobile app that allows two users to send messages to each other. The users should be able to have a list of people to contact, have a way to look at messages, and have a way to send messages to specific people. Since this is an application that needs to hold data and allow a user to modify and interact with that data, the MVC architecture would be a good way to go.

For the model component, we will need classes that represent the data that we are storing and interacting with. That means we will probably need a `Contact` class, a `Message` class, and maybe a `Conversation` class that holds an ordered list of `Message`s with another `Contact`, as well as a `Directory` class that holds a list of `Contact`s. So with our `src` directory we would have a `model` directory that holds all of those classes.

The view component depends largely on what the app is being built on. For android, you would define a set of `View`s and `ViewGroup`s that show up on screen for the user to interact with. You can stuff all of those together into a single `view` directory (or package if you're using Java.)

There needs to be a way for the user to interact with the views and cause changes with the data. This code would sit in the `controller` directory. You can have separate controllers for separate functions of the app--modifying a contact list, sending and receiving messages, etc.

At that point, you just put classes and functions and variables in those separate pieces according to the need they fill. You'll want to have a way to add and remove contacts, so have methods like `addContact` and `removeContact` in the `Directory` class that the controller can use to make that change. The view should be able to let the controller know that a contact needs to be deleted, so design it to have a delete button, and then have the delete button notify the controller that a specific contact needs to be deleted.

Follow this pattern for every piece of your project and keep good naming conventions and coding practices, and before you know it you'll have built something valuable and easily maintained.